# Add transparency handling (alpha set response) to unity shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, alpha

I have got a shader for a line renderer that does not respond to alpha change. Taking a look to the code that makes sense.
I cannot use a default material with alpha handling because the line rendeder does not paint it properly (it behaves as a billboard and its not rendered correctly). So I would like to incorporate alpha handling to my shader.

The shader finally returns tho color in the line:

```
finalColor = _Color;
```

But I cannot figure out how to pass in the alpha, so that I can handle the transparency in the editor or with code when this shader is used in a unity material.

Find below the shader code:

```
Shader "CustomShaders/UnlitColorAbove"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color("Color", Color) = (0,0,0,0)
    }
    
    SubShader
    {
        
        
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        CGINCLUDE
        #pragma target 3.0
        ENDCG
        Blend Off
        Cull Back
        ColorMask RGBA
        ZWrite On
        ZTest Always
        
        
        
        Pass
        {
            Name "Unlit"
            
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"            

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
                
            };
            
            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
                
            };

            uniform float4 _Color;
            
            v2f vert ( appdata v )
            {
                v2f o;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_INSTANCE_ID(v, o);

                
                float4 vertexValue =  float3(0,0,0,0) ;
                #if ASE_ABSOLUTE_VERTEX_POS
                v.vertex.xyzw = vertexValue;
                #else
                v.vertex.xyzw += vertexValue;
                #endif
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }
            
            fixed4 frag (v2f i ) : SV_Target
            {
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(i);
                fixed4 finalColor;
                
                
                finalColor = _Color;
                return finalColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    CustomEditor "ASEMaterialInspector"
}
```

And some of the things I tried to incorporate alpha handling to the shader:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/676989/how-can-i-add-transparency-to-this.html

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-add-support-to-alpha-on-this-shader.494460/

[Add alpha to shader in Unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330902/add-alpha-to-shader-in-unity3d)

But did not succed because the shader does not work or does not compile, as I am not familiar with shader programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [third link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330902/add-alpha-to-shader-in-unity3d) you provided* shows what your shader is actually missing to support alpha transparency.

You need to add alpha blending into your shader, so instead of:

```
Blend Off
```

It should be, for example**:

```
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

And more or less thats it***

---

I have also noticed that you are using Amplify Shader Editor (because there is the comment at the bottom of your code  `CustomEditor "ASEMaterialInspector"`)

The settings you are looking for are here:

[image]

---

.* The two previous thread you linked talk about adding alpha transparency to surface shaders while the shader you provided is a vertex-fragment shader.

.** For more info about types of blending [see unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html)). Also I could recommend [this cool talk about VFX in Diablo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPy2hytwDLM&t=2420s) which shows how the selection of proper blending can be important for you shader.

.*** You have a typo in line `float4 vertexValue =  float3(0,0,0,0) ;` it should be `float4(0,0,0,0)`, also you should consider changing `Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }` to `Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" }` and you can read more about SubShader tags [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html)

Comment: I had to add the alpha blend in the advanced options. Not the render type and the render queue though. Thank you so much for the solution and for such a detailed answer